# Why Angular HTTP Post method Error: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined?

Tags: node.js, angular, post

> Angular HTTP Post method  Error: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined.
> I am trying to make my first http POST request.But it not working

```
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  [x: string]: any;

firstnameControl = new FormControl();  //To get values


  hide=true;
  constructor( ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }


  signup(){
    //1.Collect Parameters
    let body = new HttpParams({
      fromObject:{
          'firstname': this.firstnameControl.value,
      }
    });
    
    //2.Send to URL
    var url ="http://52.15.72.215:3000/api/user";
    this.http.post(url ,body).subscribe(
      ( data: any) =>{
          alert(data);
        }
    );
    
  }

  

}
```

> Why this post method not working

---

Comment: well seems `this.http` is `undefined`, as the error states. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Compile is successfully but does not pass the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nirodha, you need to put the provider in the constructor if you want to use http request:

1. Import the HttpClient:

   import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
2. Put the HttpClient in the constructor:

   constructor(private http: HttpClient){}
3. In your app.module.ts you need to put in the imports array it:

   imports: [HttpClientModule]

And remember to import at the beginning of your code

```
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
```

Comment: Thank you, that is work after defining constructor(private http: HttpClient){}